# Heroku push to production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, heroku, production-environment

I set up my staging and production environments on heroku, and pushed to both and it worked fine. I came back a day later and was able to push to staging but got the following message about `git push production master`:

```
fatal: 'production' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Check your `history` and make sure that's actually the command you used previously. The error indicates that either you're not in the correct folder or that the use of `production` in this way is causing git to think you're referring `production` as a repository or git remote branch, where none of any such name exists. In other words, you probably have a simple typo that should be relatively easy to uncover.

Comment: Try running `git remote -v`, it will list all your remote aliases and their respective URLs.

Comment: @normalocity Thanks, but I'm pretty sure this is the exact command, I wrote it down for my reference; I cannot find it in the history though.. where can I find how it is called? is there a command I can run to find out? or perhaps I can find out somewhere in heroku's web gui?

Comment: @mmichael hi, thanks, I tried that but I don't see the prodcution env! I only see staging, github and git - which I believe is the same as staging? or perhaps it isn't? and production is set as `heroku` and staging is separate? i thought that the defauls was staging, now it seems not to be so?

Comment: Look inside your `.git/config` file inside the local copy of your repository - is there a remote reference named `production`? The standard push to heroku goes: `git push heroku [branch name]` so if you're substituting `heroku` with `production` then there should be an equivalent entry in the `.git/config` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To confirm where each remote points to, login to Heroku and open the settings to your app and then match the git URL of the app to the ones displayed by `git remote -v`. Then, if necessary, add a remote for production (i.e. `heroku`).